# Checking Array For Multiple Values and Change Output If Value Exists

Tags: php, arrays

After wrenching my brain for multiple hours, trying multiple solutions and checking Stack Overflow for PHP-based solutions to my problem -- I'm reaching out for help.

**What I'm trying to accomplish (via PHP):**

1. Check array to see if certain values exist.
2. For each value that does -> show green checkmark icon
3. If the value doesn't exist -> show red X icon

**My problem:**

1. I'm performing the above steps, checking for multiple values.
2. I'm trying to call the API endpoint that I receive the array data from only one time, instead of once per check.

**Example Setup:**

amenitiesArray = ['amenityX', 'smoking', 'pets', 'amenityY', 'amenityZ', 'amenityA', 'linens', 'amenityB', 'wifi']

If amenitiesArray contains smoking, show a green check.

If amenitiesArray doesn't contain smoking, show a red X.

Perform the above 2 steps, checking for multiple other values...like...

If amenitiesArray contains pets, show a green check.

If amenitiesArray doesn't contain pets, show a red X.

All values I'm looking for: linens, wifi, pets and smoking.

**Helpful Note:** The amenitiesArray values are different for each product/rental property. The amenitiesArray may or may not contain the values I'm checking for.

Ultimately, for each rental property, I'm trying to display a table that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JRvo.png

What is the best way to achieve this with PHP?

Comment: What are the other 6 values?  Please show all input, the master list of all values to check for.

Comment: Your image shows just four checks, but you always want to show all 9 checks for each property?

Comment: @ju1985oh StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. Many users have posted valid answers. What they aren't going to do is write all of the code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `in_array()`  *I'm always checking for the same 4 values (smoking, linens, wifi, linens). For each of the 4 values, I need to display a green check if it exists in the array, or a red X if it does not.*

As per comment this what you need to do using in_array

```
`$amenitiesArray = ['amenityX', 'smoking', 'pets', 'amenityY', 'amenityZ', 'amenityA', 'linens', 'amenityB', 'wifi'] //from api`

 $your_data = ['smoking','pets','linens','wifi'];

echo "<table boder='1px'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr><th>column1</th><th>colum2</th></tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";
foreach($your_data as $row)
{

    echo "<tr><td>".$row."</td>";

    if(in_array($row,$amenitiesArray))
     {
           echo "<td>green icon html</td>";
      }
      else
      {
          echo "<td>red icon html</td>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
} 

  echo "</tbody>";
  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: @JYoThl I've added an image of the end product I'm trying to achieve -- if it helps.

Comment: it works for same just replace the green into your html icon  @ju1985oh

Comment: @JYoThI your solution worked perfectly for my complex problem.

Comment: glad to help you @ju1985oh

Comment: yeah removed   @mickmackusa

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $values contains all the values you want to check for in the $array:

```
$intersect = array_intersect($values, $array);
```

...$intersect contains values that are present in both arrays, you can loop over it and echo them with a green check mark now.

```
$diff = array_diff($values, $array);
```

...$diff contains values that are present in the first array, but not the second, you can loop over it and echo them with a cross mark now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `array_diff()` which will produce an array of values from array 1 that aren't in array 2.

Array 1 would be a list of values to check for. Array 2 would be the array to test.

Any value in the computed array, the return value of `array_diff()`, will be a red X. Any value in array 2 would be a green check.

Example:

```
// This should be an array of all values you need to test for.
$all_amenities = [ 'smoking', 'pets', 'xyz' ];
$available_amenities = [ 'pets' ];

$not_available = array_diff( $all_amenities, $available_amenities );

// loop through $available_amenities and output your green checks
// loop through $not_available and output red X
```

If however you needed to keep these items in their current order, you could use `in_array()` instead.

Example:

```
foreach ( $all_amenities as $amenity ) {
    if ( in_array( $amenity, $available_amenities ) ) {
        echo 'green check markup';
    } else {
        echo 'red X markup';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use PHP's in_array function.

[php.net in_array - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)